# Something weird about the download script

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Good day,

Just having trouble [again] with the download script. Right now, the issue is about whenever I tried to download a file, it was the download.php that has been fetching and not the MS Excel file itself. Though in the process of downloading, it shows the icon and even the application that the file I was trying to download was in excel format. But what I could not understand is as soon as I downloaded it, it would become an empty download.php

[image: downloading process]

Here are my codes for calling the download:

```
<?php 

    $up = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload");

            $CountRow=0;
            while($cr = mysql_fetch_array($up))
                {       
                echo "<div style='float:left; '>";  
                echo "<p style='padding:5px; margin:5px; border:1px solid #ccc; '>";

                echo "<a href='rental/download.php?id=".$cr['upload_id']."'><img src='images/icon.png'> </a>"." "."<a href='download.php?id=".$cr['upload_id']."'>".$cr['file_name']."  "."</a>";
                echo "</p>";
                echo "</div>";          
                }

            $CountRow++;

?>
```

And this is the download.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{

 $id    = $_GET['id'];
 $query = "SELECT file_name, file_type, file_size, content 
 FROM upload WHERE upload_id = '$id'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
 list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 header("Content-length: $size");
 header("Content-type: $type");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 echo $content;
 mysql_close();
 exit;
 }


?>
```

What am I gonna do? I wonder what went wrong...

Comment: Change `file_name` to `filename`

Comment: use `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");`

Answer (score 0):

Use `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);`

Additionally, try to use single quotes and concatenate strings, rather than double quotes.  Double quotes is like eval(), and not recommended if you don't really need it.

Also, use PDO for database access or at least mysqli, and sanitize your input before including it an SQL query. Or `'download.php?id=1'; DROP TABLE user;--` will get you. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried to change the code and it did downloaded the file so far. But I encounter another issue. Once the download process is done, the file will automatically open and when you checked the download folder or any folder where you store the file, it seems that the file is nowhere, like it wasn't downloaded. Is there something am missing?

Comment: That is a function of your browser. Some will try to open automatically. Try a right click and Save As to download to disk. Also try a different browser, so see the difference.

Comment: I took your advice. This time I used google chrome to see if it works okay. It did save but the file didn't show the icon for excel instead just a paper-like icon. and when I tried to open it, nothing happens. Same thing goes for firefox.

Comment: [download output](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/10469706_890975840918019_6848320156803364158_n.jpg)

this how it looks like when I downloaded it. The paper-like icon is what it appears like when I check the folder where I saved it.

Comment: What's the value of file_name in the database? It will need to have the correct Excel extension, and that extension will need to be associated with Excel for it to work.

Comment: the file_name column has the title of the uploaded file while the file_type is on this format application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: But what is the value?  Is it just "Spot"? or is it "Spot.xls", or "Spot.xlsx"?

Comment: it is Spot.xls. But .xlsx and .xls are just the same excel format right?

Comment: .xls and .xlsx are different formats.  .xls is the old binary style, and .xlsx is the newer archived xml style.  From the screenshot, I could not tell if there was an extension at all.  If the file has been saved as Spot.xls, but there's no automatic association with Excel, then there's a problem with the Excel installation, rather than your program downloading the file.  See if you can open the downloaded file from Excel, just to make sure the downloaded file is not corrupted.

Comment: yes I can open the file from MS Excel, but to save it is definitely an issue.

Comment: To clarify. The file is downloading successfully, because you can open it in Excel after is has saved, but the icon shown in the browser download list is not as expected?

Comment: nope. Aside from the file didn't show the proper icon for it. It cannot be saved automatically at the downloads folder or to any folder where I was about to place it. Just like a normal download should be. Unless I opened the file in MS Excel (because the window will asked whether to open or save it) and manually save it from there (you know the menu file-save as- process?)
That's when it can only be saved. But when I tried to click the download link, a download window will appear of course and asking on where to save it, when you try to save it to a folder it won't be shown. Weird isn't it?

Comment: Also, before you download it this is how it looks like. [Displayed Output](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t1.0-9/10341505_893534743995462_8537623708265464564_n.jpg)

but on the downloading window, it only shows the "Spot" name while the rest including the extension is omitted.